# Replace values grouping by column in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have a pandas dataframe like this in a python script:

| column_a | column_b | column_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value_1 | type1 | 10 |
| value_2 | type1 | 20 |
| value_2 | type2 | 15 |
| value_2 | type3 | 10 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Is there a way to replace the value of *column_c* of *type1* by the sum of values of *type2* + *type_3* in that column?

Something like this:

| column_a | column_b | column_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value_1 | type1 | 10 |
| value_2 | type1 | **25** |
| value_2 | type2 | **15** |
| value_2 | type3 | **10** |
| ... | ... | ... |

What I need is group by *column_a* and set the value of *type1* in column_c_ to the sum of *type2* + *type3* if there is both types.

Comment: @sammywemmy  I think OP wants to group under same `column_a` and set `type1` value to be the sum of `type2` + `type3` within the same group.  (25 = 15 + 10) in this case.

Answer (score 1):

one way would be to calculate the needed new values by using 2 groupbys and then assign these values:

```
# calculate the new values per group
g_ab_sum = df.groupby(['column_a', 'column_b']).sum().reset_index()
g_a_sum = g_ab_sum[g_ab_sum['column_b'].isin(['type2', 'type3'])].groupby('column_a').sum().reset_index()[['column_a', 'column_c']]


# assign the new values
for x in g_a_sum.values:
    df.loc[(df['column_a']==x[0]) & (df['column_b']=='type1'), 'column_c'] = x[1]
```

Comment: It looks great if there is just a value in _column_a_, but if there is multiple values in this column it get some weird values (I don't know which is the relation between this value and originals of _column_c_). I'll explain with real data in original post.

Comment: hmm, the numbers you show probably derive from values not seen in the question, I'll try to think of a way to get it on my side

Comment: Sorry, you are right, that numbers derive from values not seen in the examples of the question. The data have more columns and I did'n modify  the x[0] and x[1] values. Although I changed these values by the column index and it does'n change the value of _type1_.

Comment: maybe maybe it's because you have more columns in the groupby. see my edit which might fix it